# How to GroupBy this data in Pandas, Python?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my below table in Pandas. I have almost 40k rows which have OpenTime, ClosedTime, Reopen Time as headers. I want to GroupBy all the
three columns such that,

```
       OpenTime     ClosedTime  ReopenTime   ID

0       Afternoon   Afternoon   Afternoon    484
1       Evening     Afternoon   Afternoon    44
2       Morning     Morning     Evening      23
3       Night       Evening     Evening
10,000  Morning     Afternoon   Night
12,000  Morning     Evening     Morning
40,000  Night       Morning     Night
```

This is the resultant data that I want.

```
        OpenTime  ClosedTime ReopenTime
Morning 5644         4555     4444
Night   444           333     333
```

This is some of the code that I tried,

```
df1 = df.groupby(['OpenTime']).size().reset_index()
df1
```

I got this as a result, which is wrong (I even tried doing `GroupBy` on 2-3 columns and I'm not sure how to go about it. Do help, thanks.

```
    OpenTime    0
0   Afternoon   16395
1   Evening 16813
2   Morning 9876
3   Night   546
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df2 = df.melt('ID').groupby(['value','variable']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('ID')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['value'], df1['variable'])
print (df2)
variable   ClosedTime  OpenTime  ReopenTime
value                                      
Afternoon           3         1           2
Evening             2         1           2
Morning             2         3           1
Night               0         2           2
```

EDIT: If need specified columns for `melting`:

```
df2 = (df.melt(value_vars=['OpenTime','ClosedTime','ReopenTime'])
         .groupby(['value','variable'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

---

```
df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['OpenTime','ClosedTime','ReopenTime'])
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['value'], df1['variable'])
```

**Details**:

First melting `unpivot` data - if use `id_vars` is identifier, so all another columns are considered measured columns (`value_vars`):

```
print (df.melt(id_vars='ID'))
       ID    variable      value
0   484.0    OpenTime  Afternoon
1    44.0    OpenTime    Evening
2    23.0    OpenTime    Morning
3     NaN    OpenTime      Night
4     NaN    OpenTime    Morning
5     NaN    OpenTime    Morning
6     NaN    OpenTime      Night
7   484.0  ClosedTime  Afternoon
8    44.0  ClosedTime  Afternoon
9    23.0  ClosedTime    Morning
10    NaN  ClosedTime    Evening
11    NaN  ClosedTime  Afternoon
12    NaN  ClosedTime    Evening
13    NaN  ClosedTime    Morning
14  484.0  ReopenTime  Afternoon
15   44.0  ReopenTime  Afternoon
16   23.0  ReopenTime    Evening
17    NaN  ReopenTime    Evening
18    NaN  ReopenTime      Night
19    NaN  ReopenTime    Morning
20    NaN  ReopenTime      Night
```

Or is possible defined only `value_vars` columns:

```
print (df.melt(value_vars=['OpenTime','ClosedTime','ReopenTime']))
      variable      value
0     OpenTime  Afternoon
1     OpenTime    Evening
2     OpenTime    Morning
3     OpenTime      Night
4     OpenTime    Morning
5     OpenTime    Morning
6     OpenTime      Night
7   ClosedTime  Afternoon
8   ClosedTime  Afternoon
9   ClosedTime    Morning
10  ClosedTime    Evening
11  ClosedTime  Afternoon
12  ClosedTime    Evening
13  ClosedTime    Morning
14  ReopenTime  Afternoon
15  ReopenTime  Afternoon
16  ReopenTime    Evening
17  ReopenTime    Evening
18  ReopenTime      Night
19  ReopenTime    Morning
20  ReopenTime      Night
```

Last is created crosstab between `variable` and `value` columns for count  simple cross tabulation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure how to use this, I have 'ClosedTime', 'OpenTime', as columns, I tried replacing it in the code but I am unable to get it work.

Comment: @DineshGupta - There is error? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, I am getting keyerror, 'OpenTime'. df2 = df.melt('Case Number (Interaction ID)').groupby(['Afternoon','ClosedTime']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

I don't need ID for anything actually, we can ignore it. Please let me know what syntax should be right, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! It worked, if you don't mind, can you explain a bit in-depth how did you go about this? Thanks again.